# AWS OpsWorks Multiple Custom Chef Recipes - Berkshelf

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services

Can I utilize Berkshelf in AWS OpsWorks if I want multiple cookbooks under the same repo? I'm currently using bitbucket and have the custom recipes working. However, I only have one cookbook and need to add a few more. Can I just create a directory structure under my one repo for the multiple cookbooks? Or do I need to do multiple repos, one for each cookbook? I know I can use the Berkshelf Berksfile to include all of the cookbooks, but I can't get it to work properly.

Cookbooks would be:

```
custom  
-->recipes  
-->attributes  

deploy  
-->recipes  
-->attributes  

nodejs  
-->recipes  
-->attributes  
-->providers  
-->libraries  
-->resources
```

Can I just create the directory structure like above under the same repo, or would I need to split those 3 cookbooks out into their own repos and use the Berksfile?

Comment: the way i've done it in the past is via the Berksfile

Comment: My question would be, if I use Berksfile do I have to have separate repos for each cookbook? Or can I have them in the same repo?

Comment: you should be able to have them in the same repo

Comment: I see in AWS docs that you can have a single repo with each cookbook being its own directory.

Do you have an example Berskfile? I'm having issues defining each cookbook. Do I have to specify the git repository for each one even though it's the same repository?

Comment: I was able to get it. In the Berksfile line for each cookbook, you need the rel: option at the end to tell it to look under that subdirectory. Working great now, thanks!

Comment: @hiddenicon, a more complete example may be useful. Can you please respond to your own question in the form of an Answer?